# Sublime hates "..\save\" - screws up code color and layout. How to fix?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I've been using Sublime + UnrealScript plugin to program in UnrealScript, with UDK. But I was programming a save game system up, and got to adding a custom folder (..\save) when Sublime did this:

[image: string coloring]

It seems to be related to /* and the "" - Sublimes treating it like I'm missing a "

This also happens with '' as well.

This could be an issue with the UnrealScript plugin, I don't know. I would at least like to know why this is happening, as it seems to be a interpretation of sublime gone wrong (as in, Sublime thinks I'm doing / trying to do something, when really I'm not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably isn't the highlighted one, instead it's the next one followed by `"`.  The `\` character, as you may be aware, is an escape character (at least in many languages).

I am not familiar with your US language, but my bet is that is the issue there.

So you may need:

```
"..\Save\\"
```

Instead.

If US doesn't do that, which I would find surprising, then perhaps it's just the syntax highlighter getting confused.  The real tell, obviously, is if it runs as expected.

Comment: I do know its the highlighter getting confused. However the issue is that "\\" will have it look for "..\Save\\" the ..\ means look in root, but \\ means nothing - it will for that \\ as part of the filename, which I dont want

Comment: Pretty much every language I've seen on Windows allows you to use `/` instead of `\\`. If you do that, you avoid these troubles. Dunno if that's the case with UnrealScript,but it's worth a try.

Comment: You clever clever person! Works fine now that I'm using / instead of \ - thanks. Can't believe I forgot to try that!